# What would happen if an illegal immigrant's country of citizenship can't be established?

Tags: united-states, immigration, illegal-immigration

Imagine a person is detained for being an illegal immigrant in the US, fully admits it, and makes zero attempt to contest their deportation. However, this person refuses to state what country they're from, and the authorities don't find any foreign passport or other evidence.

What would happen to this person, given that the government wouldn't know where to deport them to?

Note that in this hypothetical the person is not claiming to be stateless, and fully admits to being the citizen of some country, but refuses to say which.

Comment: Starts with a t...

Comment: @27096 I have no idea what you're alluding to.

Comment: @BrennanVincent I think the approved euphemism is "enhanced interrogation".

Comment: @emory I am asking about the law, not what the CIA could hypothetically do illegally.